# Update a memo field in Access table

Tags: ms-access, vba

- Table Name: `MissingT`
- Column Names: Worklog (Momo) , Webid (text)

`Worklog` column has data in it which could be wrong. I have a form that will bring this kind worklog to be re-entered one after the other. But when I re-enter a worklog, I want an update query to update all the other "worklog" that has the same webid, with the re-entered worklog.

```
UPDATE MissingT 
SET Worklog = DMin("Worklog","MissingT","WebID='" & [WebID] & "'");.
```

When I run this query to update, I am getting unknown error.

The Form will pull all the information on that line and will let the user to delete the text for worklog and  enter new one. All the other fields are lock for editing. Once the user enters the new worklog, click next to find the next incorrect worklog, while updating as intended above.

This single form grabs information using a query as it's record source "QryNullAuthManager"

```
SELECT 
    MissingT.[Case ID+], MissingT.[Requester Login+], 
    MissingT.[Requester Name+], MissingT.[Due Date], 
    MissingT.[Client Login+], MissingT.[Client Name+], 
    MissingT.Status, MissingT.[Case Information], 
    MissingT.AuthManager, MissingT.FID, MissingT.Worklog, 
    MissingT.WebID
FROM 
    MissingT
WHERE 
    (((MissingT.AuthManager) Is Null)) OR (((MissingT.FID) Is Null));
```

[image]

Comment: What is the Form setup? One button, with one text box?

Comment: updated my original request with your question.

Comment: The Form will pull all the information on that line and will let the user to delete the text for worklog and enter new one. All the other fields are lock for editing. Once the user enters the new worklog, click next to find the next incorrect worklog, while updating as intended above.

Comment: I asked the form setup, you gave me an explanation of the work flow. What information I need is, is this for Continuous or Single? If single, how is the setup. Is this Form Bound or unbound? A screenshot might help.

Comment: Updated my original post as per to your request.